# How I can create handler for dead-letter queue in Azure using MassTransit?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I need to process messages in dead-letter queue. How I can create handler for this? Also I need to handle messages from error queue that also fell into dead-letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris Paterson(owner of [MassTransit.AzureServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.AzureServiceBus/)) mentioned that there is no MassTransit-specifc tool for your purpose. If MassTransit is not mandatory, we can hand the dead-letter queue with Azure Service Bus SDK. The dead-letter queue fully supports peek-lock delivery and transactional operations. More details about dead-letter, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues).

We also can get the [demo code about dead-letter](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-servicebus-messaging-samples/tree/master/DeadletterQueue) from  github.  The following code is the snippet from the demo code.

```
  var deadletterReceiver = await receiverFactory.CreateMessageReceiverAsync(QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(queueName), ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
  while (true)
  {
       var msg = await deadletterReceiver.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.Zero);
       if (msg != null)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Deadletter message:");
          foreach (var prop in msg.Properties)
          {
               Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Key, prop.Value);
          }
          await msg.CompleteAsync();
          }
          else
          {
               break;
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like Service Bus Explorer to move messages from a dead-letter queue back into the queue, and likewise for messages in the error queue. There isn't a MassTransit-specific tool for this purpose.

If you have known errors that would cause messages to fail, you can use features of Service Bus such as scheduling messages for future delivery instead of throwing the exception all the way back to MassTransit and having it move to the error queue.